# How to get application's information on appstore?

Tags: ios

I have an application on AppStore. But I cannot get its information. With example follow on: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/iTuneSearchAPI/LookupExamples.html. But my application’s response content is always empty.

Please help me!

PS. My API:  https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=(myAppID)

```
{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}
```

Comment: Your appID should be all numbers, and not begin with `id`. See if that helps.

Comment: The url for Shazam would be `https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284993459` and it works for me.

Comment: Can you please provide more details because I have tried with 2 app ID and always it is working fine. so if possible so provide your app ID

Comment: My app ID: 1439760873.

Comment: is your app live? If app is not live then it will never work. Can you please give me link of your app store webpage. https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1439760873, this one shows that such app doesnt exists. It clearly means that above url will give 0 results.

Comment: In objective c, `NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    
    NSString *appID = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID];`

Comment: my app live. But it only available for Viet Nam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass country code as param if app is available on specific iTune store. In your case complete url is [`https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1439760873&country=vn`](https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1439760873&country=vn). You can found more detail on [`https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/`](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/).

Comment: @thanhbao- accept & upvote if working for you, happy coding :)

Comment: We can add multiple countries like this? &country=vn&contry=in